# Как можно сделать фото с камеры (webcam photo)?

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли это сделать без jQuery и сторонних плагинов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Flash. [Access Webcam with Flash](http://www.kevinmusselman.com/2009/02/access-webcam-with-flash/)
- Silverlight. [Capturing the Webcam in Silverlight 4](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Capturing-the-Webcam-in-Silverlight-4.aspx)
- HTML5. [Capturing Audio & Video in HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

Comment: Минусую, ибо перечисленные флешрояли противоречат условию *без сторонних плагинов*. Валидна только последняя ссылка, в которой всё печально по внедренческой части.

Comment: @karmadro4, сторонние плагины - это javascript плагины имелись в виду как я понял (prototype, underscore, extjs и т.д.). учитывая замечание по поводу html5, совсем без плагинов - это зайти в квартиру и сфотать на айфон.